# Error handling but still getting a ValueError

Tags: python, string, error-handling

I am trying to solve this challenge about error-handling. Maybe I'm way off!

The challenge description:

> Write a function called "load_file" that accepts one parameter: a filename. The function should open the file and return the contents.
>
> If the contents of the file can be interpreted as an integer, return the contents as an integer. Otherwise, if the contents of the file can be interpreted as a float, return the contents as a float. Otherwise, return the contents of the file as a string.
>
> You may assume that the file has only one line.

I get ValueError: could not convert string to float: "b>a!\{\'"

Am I all wrong about the error-handling?

```
def load_file(file):
    
    file = open(file, "r")
    all_lines = file.read()
    
    try:        
        return int(all_lines)
    
    except ValueError:
        return float(all_lines)
            
    else:
        return all_lines
            
   
    file.close()
```

Comment: You do understand that only the code in the `try` block is protected, right?

Comment: The question is a bit misleading as a `float` can also be interpreted as integer. `int(3.3)` gives you `3`. This means trying to cast to `int` first will lead to a `float` interpreted as `int` without throwing a `ValueError`

Answer (score 3):

You need to do something like

```
with open(file, "r") as file_handle:
    all_lines = file.read()
    try:
        return int(all_lines)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    try:
        return float(all_lines)
    except ValueError:
        pass

    return all_lines
```

The point is you don't really care about the errors at all, because they just mean you need to proceed to the next option.

I would also point out that the `with` construct takes care of closing the file for you. If you want to do `file = open(file, "r")` then you will need to store your return value to a variable, and then do `file.close()` before you `return`.

Comment: As I mentioned in my comment to the question, all floats can be represented as int. Therefore if it is really a float in the file, you're code where you cast it to float will never be reached.

Comment: I ran this through the python interactive shell just now:

`>>> int("1234.4341")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1234.4341'
`

Comment: @Igle That's not right. `int('3.0')` throws an exception.

Answer (score 1):

You handle the `ValueError` thrown by using the `int()` function, but there's the possibility of `float()` also throwing such an error. The purpose of the [try/catch structure](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) is for running code inside the `try` block that may throw any exception, such as a `ValueError`, and to execute "error handler" code inside the `except` block.

Comment: Thats wrong as `else` can be used as part of a `try, catch`. See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

Comment: Thats true, he does not need it.

Comment: I completely forgot about that syntax since I don't think I've ever really used it, edited my post

Answer (score 1):

when you try to parse as a float there is also an exception. you can try something like this

```
def load_file(file):

    file = open(file, "r")
    all_lines = file.read()

    try:        
        return int(all_lines)

    except ValueError:
        try:
            return float(all_lines)
        except ValueError:
             return all_lines

    file.close()
```

You can nest trys inside of exceptions to get it to do what you want

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your approach is that the `float(all_lines)` can fail but that exception isn't handled.

So it should be:

```
try:        
    return int(all_lines)
except ValueError:  # handle the exception if it's not an integer
    try:
        return float(all_lines)
    except ValueError:  # handle the exception if it's not a float
        return all_lines
```

But you could also just [`suppress`](https://docs.python.org/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.suppress) errors (requires python 3.3 or newer though). This could reduce the length of the code and the number of nested `try` and `except`s:

```
from contextlib import suppress

def load_file(file):
    with open(file, "r") as file:  # using open with "with" closes the file automatically.
        all_lines = file.read()

    with suppress(ValueError):
        return int(all_lines)
    with suppress(ValueError):
        return float(all_lines)
    return all_lines
```